# Use PHP to include an HTML file as a jQuery object

Tags: php, jquery, html

Let's say I have a "test.html" file with some example content:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>'Test'</td>
  <td>Test "2"</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to use that as a jQuery object.  My first instinct would be to attempt:

```
var $testobject = $("<?php include('./test.html');?>");
```

But with the line breaks and quotes in test.html, this would fail.  I specifically need the test.html file to be a jQuery object so it is hidden on load and is put in different places on the page with various triggered scripts, and I would prefer to use the more static PHP approach than a jQuery load.  There must be a simple trick to manage this...

Comment: Try use `file_get_contents` instead `include`.

Comment: You could simply load the object into a variable using the jQuery [ajax load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

Comment: I specifically don't want to use the jQuery load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the static file using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents), and deal with special characters using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
var $testobject = $(<?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents('./test.html'));?>);
```

For example, if `test.html` contains:

```
<a href="/">
  Test
</a>
```

Then the output will be:

```
var $testobject = $("<a href=\"\/\">\n  Test\n<\/a>\n");
```

Comment: Using my example test.html, this fails with this test.php file (nothing appears):

<html><body>
<script>
var $testthing = <?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents('./test.html'));?>;
$testthing.appendTo(document.body);
</script>
</body></html>

Comment: I should add that the PHP echo succeeds, the HTML appears as you describe it.  But it doesn't display from appending to the document body...

Comment: @user You're missing the jQuery wrapper. **`$(`** `<?php ... ?>` **`);`**.

Comment: Oops, added jQuery wrapper and still nothing: var $testthing = $(<?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents('./test.html'));?>);

Comment: @user173342 You did never load the jQuery library.. See http://pastebin.com/jEpKRqq1 for the corrected version. (PHP: http://pastebin.com/RjN7H8sP).

Comment: Ok, I'm sorta new with jQuery and forgot about that.  Sorry for being an idiot, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

use load :

create a div

```
$('#test').load('test.html');
```

var testObject = $('#div').find('table');

Answer (score 0):

use output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include('./test.html');
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>

var $testobject = $("<?=$data;?>");
```